# .net change Process Windows font

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a code like this :

```
 Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("ABC.EXE")
 psi.RedirectStandardError = True
 psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
 psi.CreateNoWindow = False
 psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
 psi.UseShellExecute = False
 psi.WorkingDirectory = "n:\invdat"
 Dim p As Process = Process.Start(psi)
```

This program start an Character base application. I wants to change the font of this caracters base application.

I wants to reproduce the change via top left click on the Application ICON and select Properties

Comment: In Visual Studio desktop you have three common choices; Console application, and forms: WinForms or WPF. If you want to have a menu your program can use WinForms/WPF is the way to go. The "form" could just host a single textbox docked to the edges of the form. If you are thinking of mobile- like apps I'm not sure what is the best choice. What development environment are you using? What is the target platform.

Comment: My process is an old TextBase application. I don't wants to rewrite-it, only launch my application (a WinForm application) inside my current application. When I launch my application (via Process.Start) this application open in a very small windows. I wants to change the font of this windows.

Answer (score 0):

If the legacy program uses standard out this may work to capture the output.

```
        Dim start_info As New ProcessStartInfo("RoboCopy", sParams)
        start_info.UseShellExecute = False
        start_info.CreateNoWindow = True
        start_info.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        start_info.RedirectStandardError = True

        ' Make the process and set its start information.
        Dim proc As New Process()
        proc.StartInfo = start_info

        ' Start the process.
        proc.Start()

        ' Attach to stdout and stderr.
        Dim std_out As StreamReader = proc.StandardOutput()
        Dim std_err As StreamReader = proc.StandardError()

        ' Get the results.
        Dim sOut As String = std_out.ReadToEnd()
        Dim sErr As String = std_err.ReadToEnd()
```

You can then display the results from sOut in a Winform.

Comment: My program is a complete TextBase application with Menu, edit section. this is an Old Cobol App.

Comment: Unlikely you will be able to change the display font from outside the program. Slight chance you may be able to capture the text using SendKeys. If the app has menu to change font SendKeys might work. Look for registry entries regard display fonts for the Cobol App. Are there any tags for the Cobol platform you could add to the OP?